# Ruby - when is block executed?

Tags: ruby, closures, block

I understood how ruby's `block` works.

***block_test.rb***

```
def foo
  yield if block_given?
end

my_block = foo { puts "hello" }
```

if I run, `ruby block_test.rb`. Of course it print 'hello' as you expected.

```
hello
```

But my question is when did I execute ruby block?
I did not call foo method in anywhere.

I didn't write - `foo()` stuff like that.

```
# I defined `foo` method here as [If a block has been given, execute it.] but did not call.
def foo
  yield if block_given?
end

# I also defined block of `foo` as [print 'hello'] and store into `my_block` variable. 
# But I did not say execute `foo`. Did I?
my_block = foo { puts "hello" }
```

So my assumption is..
***When you declare block, It implicitly means that it will execute the method with the same name of the block***

Please correct me If I am missing something.

Comment: _I did not call foo method_, yes, you did. With `foo { puts "hello" }` you're calling `foo`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Does it mean when I am defining my block and call at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I didn't write - `foo()` stuff like that.

In Ruby, parentheses are optional when calling methods. You can call a method without parentheses. For example, `puts` is often called without parentheses like this:

```
puts "hello"
```

You are calling your method here:

```rb
my_block = foo { puts "hello" }
#          ^^^
```

> So my assumption is..
>   ***When you declare block, It implicitly means that it will execute the method with the same name of the block***

It is unclear what you are asking here. A block doesn't have a name, so "the method with the same name of the block" doesn't make sense. A block is a special argument to a method call. It cannot appear anywhere else except as the last argument of a method call. It cannot be assigned to a variable, it cannot be returned from a method, it cannot be given a name. It is not an object or a value.